# Creating a Azure VM using Azure Resource Manger API

Tags: rest, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

**I am using following azure rest api to create a virtual machine in Azure Resource Manager mode**

> PUT
>   https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vm-name}?validating={true|false}&api-version={api-version}

The virtual machine gets created and it remains in Creating state as i can see the status or new portal of azure
I am able to RDP into the machine. 
But after a login it fails.

What could be the reason?
Any thing i am missing?

**Note : I am creating a virtual machine using a image.**
Request Json :

```
{
  "properties": {
    "hardwareProfile": {
      "vmSize": "Standard_A0"
    },
    "storageProfile": {

      "osDisk": {
            "osType": "Windows",
            "name": "goldentemplate-osDisk",
            "createOption": "FromImage",
            "image": {
              "uri": "https://storagename.blob.core.windows.net/system/Microsoft.Compute/Images/mytemplates/goldentemplate-osDisk.vhd"
            },
            "vhd": {
              "uri": "https://storagename.blob.core.windows.net/vmcontainersagar/sagargoden.vhd"
            },
            "caching": "None"
          }
    ,


      "dataDisks": []
    },
    "osProfile": {
      "computerName": "sagarHostVM",
      "adminUsername": "itadmin",
      "adminPassword": "Micr0s0ft12!@"
    },
    "networkProfile": {
      "networkInterfaces": [
        {
          "properties": {},
          "id": "/subscriptions/subscritpionid/resourceGroups/harigroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/sagarhostnic"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "name": "sagarHostVM",
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
  "location": "WestUs",
  "tags": {}
}
```

Comment: Regardless of the issue: It's not really good practice to publish your username and password.

Comment: However long you've used that password, you can never take it away from the Internet, so best to stop using it and never again.

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann How its showing provision state as Creating. What might be missing in my request. I am able to read the machine. can i change the provisioning stage on my own

Comment: I can see that you are using a self-uploaded image. It's probably a problem of the image.

Comment: @JackZeng. I have followed below steps . 1) Created a virtual machine using Offer-WindowsServer
Sku-Remote-Desktop-Session-Host
Version-latest  2) Created the image of virtual machine using a) deallocate b) generalized c) capture 3) Created the virtual machine given above using image from step 2) .   Is anything else i should follow ?

Comment: What do you mean by "after a login it fails"? What specifically fails? (VM status becomes stopped? RDP stops working? If so, what error does it show? etc.)